# Multiplication in Sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm writing a stored procedure. The stored procedure will take inventory for all inventory entries and return, among other things, the total cost for all units of that product. I am grouping by product and supplier information, then when it comes to the quantity and value I have this

```
SELECT i.SupplierID, i.SupplierName, p.ProductID, p.ProductName,  
       SUM(i.Quantity) AS Quantity, 
       SUM(i.Quantity * i.UnitCost) AS TotalValue, 
       SUM(i.Quantity * i.UnitCost) OVER() AS AllProductsTotal
FROM Inventory i
JOIN Products p on p.ProductID = i.ProductID
GROUP BY i.SupplierID, i.SupplierName, p.ProductID, p.ProductName
```

However when I try to run the create...

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>
> Column 'Inventory.Quantity' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
>
> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>
> Column 'Inventory.UnitCost' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

The columns are in an aggregate, and only in an aggregate, they are simply in the same aggregate together. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should "ie.ProductID" be "i.ProductID"? in the join?

Comment: `SUM() OVER()` is not an aggregate

Comment: as @Serg said and also wont return the result you want. You need a subquery or another `JOIN`

Comment: You can use `SUM(SUM(i.Quantity * i.UnitCost)) OVER()` though.

Comment: The result I want is the sum of all values in the TotalValue column, over with no arguments has always worked that way before for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right, you want to apply a windowing function to an aggregate

```
SELECT i.SupplierID, i.SupplierName, p.ProductID, p.ProductName,  
       SUM(i.Quantity) AS Quantity, 
       SUM(i.Quantity * i.UnitCost) AS TotalValue, 
       SUM(SUM(i.Quantity * i.UnitCost)) OVER() AS AllProductsTotal
FROM Inventory i
JOIN Products p on p.ProductID = ie.ProductID
GROUP BY i.SupplierID, i.SupplierName, p.ProductID, p.ProductName
```

Comment: With no partitioning. The procedure also needs to return the total of all rows, which is the windowing function, the total value of all products in inventory.

Comment: Removed partitioning. I misread 'the total cost for all units of that product' as  the requirement for partitioning by product.

Answer (score 0):

You can change code as below

```
Select *, Sum(TotalValue) as AllProductsTotal over() 
from (
   SELECT i.SupplierID, i.SupplierName, p.ProductID, p.ProductName,  
       SUM(i.Quantity) AS Quantity, 
       SUM(i.Quantity * i.UnitCost) AS TotalValue--, 
       --SUM(i.Quantity * i.UnitCost) OVER() AS AllProductsTotal
   FROM Inventory i
   JOIN Products p on p.ProductID = ie.ProductID
   GROUP BY i.SupplierID, i.SupplierName, p.ProductID, p.ProductName
) a
```

Comment: Yes I certainly could remove part of the required return to get it to work, but then I am missing two values needed for the report this proc will generate.

Comment: Nevermind I misread your answer, I didn't notice selecting from the subselect, though I think the order is supposed to be before the alias not after.